# AWS RDS download full log file (access & error)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-rds, aws-cli

I am unable to download complete logs using AWS CLI for an postgres RDS instance -

```
aws rds download-db-log-file-portion \
                        --db-instance-identifier $INSTANCE_ID \
                        --starting-token 0 --output text \
                        --max-items 99999999 \
                        --log-file-name error/postgresql.log.$CDATE-$CHOUR > DB_$INSTANCE_ID-$CDATE-$CHOUR.log
```

The log files which I see in console shows it's of ~10GB but using the CLI I always get a log file of just ~100MB.

Ref - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/download-db-log-file-portion.html

AWS docs -

> In order to download the entire file, you need --starting-token 0
>   parameter:
>
> ```
> aws rds download-db-log-file-portion --db-instance-identifier test-instance \
> --log-file-name log.txt --starting-token 0 --output text > full.txt
> ```

Can someone please suggest.

Comment: I am facing with this problem now, could you find a solution?

Comment: Not yet. You can try to look out for code using SDKs in python or Golang. As per docs, they might be able to help downloading full logs.

Comment: I found this and it worked: https://github.com/jonstacks/aws#getting-a-download-url-for-your-rds-logs

Answer (score 0):

You can download the complete file via AWS Console.
But, if you can download via script, I recommend use this method:

https://linuxtut.com/en/fdabc8bc82d7183a05f3/

Please, update variables values into script.

```
profile     = "default"
instance_id = "database-1"
region      = "ap-northeast-1"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found it much simpler to just `curl` the link the console gives you. Just output it to a file and you're done. Make sure you have ample space on disk.